# I need to sum morning shift for 8AM till 1:00PM in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum for month of January 2023 from time 8:00AM (08:00) till 1:00PM (13:00) only​.

I used the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151>=DATE(2023,1,1)+TIME(8,0,0))*(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151<=DATE(2023,1,1)+TIME(13,0,0))*(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$151))​
```

And:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$151,Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151,">="&DATE(2023,1,1)+TIME(8,0,0),date,"<="&DATE(2023,1,1)+TIME(13,0,0))​
```

Both of them gave me the wrong result​.

Comment: Post some sample data, with expected output using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Nice sharing that tool! Cool to know it exists.

Comment: I have been using it sir, found easy to use and simple too!

Comment: Without example data I can't be sure if this is a part of your ask, but the formula you have will only capture people that worked the full shift. In order to capture time for people that worked part of a shift you need add `MAX` and `MIN` in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate dates from time e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$151*
(INT(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151)>=DATE(2023,1,1))*
(INT(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151)<DATE(2023,2,1))*
(MOD(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151,1)>=TIME(8,0,0))*
(MOD(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$151,1)<TIME(13,0,0)))​
```